# Can I deal with four queues in one connection?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, node-amqp

I have 2 publish queues and 2 subscribe queues, can I deal with four queues in on connection?

```
 connection = amqp.createConnection();
 connection.on("ready", function () {
     subscribe(queue1,msg1);
     publishto(queue2,msg1);
     subscribe(queue3,msg2);
     publishto(queue4,msg2);
 }
```

or four connections?

```
subscribe1(){
connection = amqp.createConnection();
connection.on("ready", function () {
    subscribeto(queue1,msg1);
    })

subscribe2(){
connection = amqp.createConnection();
connection.on("ready", function () {
    subscribeto(queue1,msg1);
    })
......
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the node.js setup, but in Java there are connections and channels.  I would use 1 connection and 4 channels, with each channel handling 1 queue each.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP is a multiplexed protocol so one connection can handle many subscriptions. Also, it's a lot less resource intensive to utilize channels than creating tons of connections.